# Convert spark Dataframe Column nullability to False without converting to rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a data frame with columns nullability as True. Wanted to convert to False in Pyspark.

I can do it in the below way. But I don't want to convert to rdd because I'm reading as structured streaming and converting to rdd is not recommended.

```
def set_df_columns_nullable(self, spark, df, column_list, nullable=True):
        for struct_field in df.schema:
            if struct_field.name in column_list:
                struct_field.nullable = nullable
        df_mod = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
        return df_mod
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not possible in fact. Whay are yiu doing this?

Comment: Actually I'm using Abris to convert normal data to confluent avro format before writing to kafka. while I'm using to_confluent_avro function, It is throwing Not a Union exception. So It is working, If I change the nullability of the column to False.

Comment: that's different then but I meant RDDs are not supported.

Comment: Actually I'm using structured streaming, converting to rdd and backing to DF is overhead. because of this, I may miss some features

Comment: I always learnt that was not supported. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually update column nullability without casting to RDD

```scala
dataFrame
  .withColumn(columnName, new Column(AssertNotNull(col(columnName).expr)))
```

[source](https://dev.to/kevinwallimann/how-to-make-a-column-non-nullable-in-spark-structured-streaming-4b62)

Note that the above would fail at execution if you have null values